# ANDROID - Send data through json response into API using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, json

I've a JSON like this:

`{"AuditScheduleDetailID":12422,"AuditAnswerId":3,"LocalFindingID":9,"LocalMediaID":18,"Files":"adasdaf","ExtFiles":"jpg"}`

then, when I'm Copy Paste into android project, that json is changing like :

`"{\"AuditScheduleDetailID\":12422,\"AuditAnswerId\":3,\"LocalFindingID\":9," +
            "\"LocalMediaID\":18,\"Files\":\"adasdaf\",\"ExtFiles\":\"jpg\"}"`

My Code to send data is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String send = "{\"AuditScheduleDetailID\":12422,\"AuditAnswerId\":3,\"LocalFindingID\":9," +
            "\"LocalMediaID\":18,\"Files\":\"adasdaf\",\"ExtFiles\":\"jpg\"}";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uploadMedia(send);
        }
}
public void uploadMedia(String value){
        Log.d("uploading ", "test");
        Log.d("Test value : ", value);
        String urlString = "myURL"; // URL to call

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            out.close();
            urlConnection.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("error upload", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

but I get an error in logcat like below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nawadata.sqllite, PID: 8750
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nawadata.sqllite/com.example.nawadata.sqllite.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
at com.example.nawadata.sqllite.MainActivity.uploadMedia(MainActivity.java:125)
at com.example.nawadata.sqllite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can someone help me why I keep getting error `java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`? and how to fix it?

when im using postman to send data into api, the return message is success
like this:

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omKNL.png)

Comment: any idea please?

Comment: I think this error is caused by `Log.d()` method. Make sure you are not passing a `null` parameter into this method.

Comment: in the catch block try this `catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("error upload", e.printStackTrace());
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Whenever you paste a JSON response in a string variable, Android Studio automatically do the formatting which is android readable.

Change your activity code like below:

```
String send = "{\"AuditScheduleDetailID\":12422,\"AuditAnswerId\":3,\"LocalFindingID\":9," +
            "\"LocalMediaID\":18,\"Files\":\"adasdaf\",\"ExtFiles\":\"jpg\"}";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uploadMedia(send);
    }

    public void uploadMedia(String value) {
        Log.e("uploading ", "test");
        Log.e("Test value : ", value);
        String urlString = "myURL"; // URL to call

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            out.close();
            urlConnection.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error upload", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Now run and check, if it works then please let me know.

Your logcat will be like below image.

[image]

Comment: on your logcat image, why that `E/Test value` have 2 `:`?

Comment: @flix that's because of the string in Log.e.  if you remove : from  Log.e("Test value : ", value); then it will be like E/Test value: {"AuditScheduleDetailID":12422,"AuditAnswerId":3,"LocalFindingID":9,"LocalMediaID":18,"Files":"adasdaf","ExtFiles":"jpg"}

Comment: so the real String of `value` is including `:` sign? how can it be like that?
actually i dont need that `:` sign, because i need to post it into rest-api

Comment: @flix  not the value, but **:** is included with the identifier for differentiation between tag and msg. In Log.e("Test value", value); "Test value" is the string (identifier/tag) and value is another string (value/msg).

Comment: @flix don't worry it is just to debug the app. It won't make any changes to your original value. Please appreciate with upvote if you are satisfied with my answer.

Comment: @flix One more thing to remember that Log.e or Log.d should not have msg as null. If you know null msg can be there then put this code in try catch or put a null check.

Answer (score 1):

Try this because it seems like value is null.

Log.d("uploading ", "test");

if( !value.equals("") || !value.eqauls(" ") )

{

Log.d("Test value : ", value);

}

if this solution is not working then try Log.e instead of Log.d because Log.e is for use error purposes.

Also change this line in catch.

Log.e("error upload", e.getMessage());

Answer (score 0):

replace log with this line:

```
   Log.d("Test value : ", value+" ");
```

and

```
  Log.d ("error upload",e.getMessage()+" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

> use Log.e for printing error as per guide see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)
>   Replace those lines

```
 Log.d("Test value : ", ""+value);


 catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```